# Formatting a Web Parts Table on a Office 365 Sharepoint Public Facing Website

Tags: sharepoint-2010, office365

I created a custom list in Sharepoint and then inserted it into a public facing web page as an App Part. The list data displays but was unformatted. I wish to format it similar to the way I would format a "table" displayed in an HTML page using CSS3.

I had a chance to play around with the CSS. I inserted this code:

```
table {
border:3px solid #00ff00;
}

th {
border:2px solid #ff0000;
font-size:18px;
color:#0000ff;
}

td {
border:1x double #0000ff;
}
```

If you go to https://gcarterit-public.sharepoint.com/whn-report you will see the resutls.

Notice:
1. the table cells (td) don't show a border as expected

1. the text in th did not change (size and color) as expected
2. can't seem to format text in table cells

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add !important to the declarations so they override defaults.
Correct "px" in the td one:

```
td { border:1px double #0000ff !important; }
```